# working out distances between two points using google maps api?

Tags: api, google-maps

Is it possible to send two lat long points to google to calculate the distance between the two?

Comment: Go straight to [@SunnyD's answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506747/working-out-distances-between-two-points-using-google-maps-api/6419141#6419141) for the Google Maps API V3 answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a handy function

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GLatLng.distanceFrom

basically create 2 GlatLng objects then use the above method

Comment: This is for version 2 of the API - do you know if a similar thing exists in V3?

Comment: not that I know of but I guess the closest thing is using the route planner and getting the distance from that

Answer (score 10):

If you're looking to use the v3 google maps API, here is a function I use:
Note: you must add `&libraries=geometry` to your script source

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Now the function:

```
//calculates distance between two points in km's
function calcDistance(p1, p2){
  return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1, p2) / 1000).toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: I want road distance not geometric distance?

Answer (score 7):

What you're after is the **[Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)**. You don't need Google Maps to do this, you can work it out separately. There's a script to do this (in JavaScript) [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

Answer (score 3):

Yes google can do this

[google api docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GLatLng.GLatLng)

here's a piece of java script that get's the distance in km's for two points

```
function initialize() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
          map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
          map.setCenter(new GLatLng(52.6345701, -1.1294433), 13);
          map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());          
          map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
          geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

          // NR14 7PZ
          var loc1 = new GLatLng(52.5773139, 1.3712427);
          // NR32 1TB
          var loc2 = new GLatLng(52.4788314, 1.7577444);          
          alert(loc2.distanceFrom(loc1) / 1000);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

And the distance cal in c#:

```
// this returns the distance in miles. for km multiply result: * 1.609344
public static double CalculateDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2)
{
    double t = lon1 - lon2;
    double distance = Math.Sin(Degree2Radius(lat1)) * Math.Sin(Degree2Radius(lat2)) + Math.Cos(Degree2Radius(lat1)) * Math.Cos(Degree2Radius(lat2)) * Math.Cos(Degree2Radius(t));
    distance = Math.Acos(distance);
    distance = Radius2Degree(distance);
    distance = distance * 60 * 1.1515;

    return distance;
}

private static double Degree2Radius(double deg)
{
    return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
}

private static double Radius2Degree(double rad)
{
    return rad / Math.PI * 180.0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>No, but</strike> you can use Vincenty's formula, which models the shape of the Earth. It's available in [Javascript here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html).

A quite easy to parse web page is (e.g.): http://boulter.com/gps/distance/?from=51.5329855+-0.1303506&to=40.757584+-73.985642&units=m

For people who only want a quick measure of distance, check out [this gadget](http://maps.google.com/gadgets/directory?synd=mpl&backlink=http%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fie%3DUTF8%26hl%3Den%26msa%3D0%26ll%3D51.849777%2C-2.005005%26spn%3D0.089497%2C0.188141%26t%3Dh%26z%3D12%26msid%3D103027944771875072080.000462e55d09784e56337&url=http%3A%2F%2Frestonthewind.googlepages.com%2FrhumbMeasure.xml).  However, it only uses the great circle calculation.

---

As Rob notes, Google have added it, but they still only use the great circle formula, which can be inaccurate by 1/300.

Answer (score 0):

Its been many years since I did this but you could use the [Great Circle Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the distance as a number, try something like this.

```
function InitDistances() {
    var startLocation = new GLatLng(startLat, startLon);
    var endLocation = new GLatLng(endLat, endLon);
    var dist = startLocation .distanceFrom(endLocation);

    // Convert distance to miles with two decimal points precision
    return (dist / 1609.344).toFixed(2);
}
```