# How many km beetween 2 coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, coordinates, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

Is there any math fomrula to calculate how many km is beetween 2 coordinates without using google map.

So etc.

FirstCoor = 33.45674,44.3453453
SecondCoor = 34.53434,45.345325

How to get km beetween this 2 coordinates ?

Is a simle formula for that or complex?

Comment: This may help you: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: do you remember the slope formula from algebra? good times. use that to find the distance in deg, then convert deg to km.

Comment: It's a good and valid question, but badly asked and answered even worse.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not programming in particular.

Comment: yes, its about programing, show jsfiddle

Comment: @MarkWest If you copy and paste the title of this question into Google then the 1st result is what's pasted below.  This is not a question about programming.  It's a question of spoon feeding.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sYq9S/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sYq9S/1/

Comment: I dont know what to copy? please upadte jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want what's called the "[great-circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance)" between the two points.  That's basically the shortest path between two points on the surface of a sphere.  (Earth isn't *quite* a sphere, but it's close enough.)

Anyway, the point is to find the angle between the two lines from the center of the sphere to each point.  Multiply that by the radius of the sphere, and that's your distance.

One of the most basic formulas is based on the "spherical law of cosines".

[image: angle = acos((sin(lat1)*sin(lat2)) + cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(abs(lat2-lat1)))]

(Thanks, Wikipedia!  :))

**ϕ<sub>1</sub>** and **ϕ<sub>2</sub>** represent the latitudes of the two points, and **Δλ** is the difference between the longitudes. **Δσ** is the angle between the two points; assuming it's in radians, you can multiply it by the radius of the sphere, and that gives you the length of the arc that connects them.

In JavaScript:

```
function arc_distance(loc1, loc2) {
    var rad  = Math.PI / 180,
        earth_radius = 6371.009, // close enough
        lat1 = loc1.lat * rad,
        lat2 = loc2.lat * rad,
        dlon = Math.abs(loc1.lon - loc2.lon) * rad,
        M    = Math;

    return earth_radius * M.acos(
        (M.sin(lat1) * M.sin(lat2)) + (M.cos(lat1) * M.cos(lat2) * M.cos(dlon))
    );
}
```

When this formula was first used on computers, it really sucked with short distances.  But numbers were quite a bit smaller back then, too.  With numbers in JS being 64-bit, the accuracy is much better than some people have warned about.  It can easily deal with distances less than a kilometer, and even at less than a meter it's reasonably close to other methods.

Comment: @MarkWest: Pretty much.  Though your coordinates would be like `var coords1 = { lat: 33.4444, lon: 34.5454545 };`.

Comment: @MarkWest: Standard JS doesn't have a `print` function, AFAIK...and even if it did, you wouldn't call it like that.  (Edit: Actually, it appears `window.print()` fires up a printer dialog in Chrome.  Which still isn't what you want.)

Comment: so, this also dont return result alert (arc_distance(loc1,loc2));

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the traveling distence. right? The formula from the following link give only the straight line distence from one point to another.

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

if you need exact travel distence from one point to another point use **google distance matrix**.
you can find it on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

reffer this answer too.
   [working out distances between two points using google maps api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506747/working-out-distances-between-two-points-using-google-maps-api/6419141#6419141)