# Get all latitude and longitude of one kilometer distance

Tags: django, python-3.x, location, latitude-longitude

I want to get all the lat and long of the user with in 1 km distance. For example i have the user current location latitude and longitude i want to find all of his friends with in 1 km distance.

```
User1 current Latitude : '25.276987'
User1 current Longitude: '55.296249'
```

Similarly I have all the other users lat and long with me.

```
{'user2':{lat:'25.122212','long':'55.296249'},'user3':{lat:'25.222212','long':'55.396249'}}
```

I want to find all the other users who are in 1 km distance of user1.

i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29001716/compute-latitude-and-longitude-to-kilometer) but did not help me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, it should be other way round. You can calculate the distance between the User and his/her friends, and determine if they are in 1 KM of the user. You can simply do it like this(I am using [GeoPy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#module-geopy.distance) for this example):

```
from geopy import distance

def get_distance(user_co, friend_co):
    coords_1 = (user_co.get('lat'), user_co.get('long'))
    coords_2 = (float(friend_co.get('lat')), float(friend_co.get('long')))

    return distance.distance(coords_1, coords_2).km


user = {'lat': 25.276987, 'long': 55.296249}
friends= {'user2':{ 'lat':'25.122212','long':'55.296249'},'user3':{ 'lat':'25.222212','long':'55.396249'}}

for key, value in friends.items():
    dstnce =  get_distance(user, value)
    if dstnce < 1:
        print("Friend {} is in 1 KM".format(key))
```

You can look into [this so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412462/getting-distance-between-two-points-based-on-latitude-longitude) for more details on distance calculation.

Comment: Thanks you save my day